# Automatically download sources in Gradle project

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

In Maven projects, there is an option to automatically download sources (and javadoc) for all libraries. For Gradle project I found no option, just to open a class and click "Search in internet". This is very annoying if you have a lot of libraries. Is there any way to automatically attach sources from the internet (maven repo)?

Comment: On the idea plugin it is default on when running **gradle idea**. But I guess that doesn't help much?

Comment: You'd have to explain in detail how you are importing the project into IntelliJ. Downloading sources and making them available to the IDE is the default in Gradle.

Comment: You are right. Actually i was importing the gradle project itself. I ran `gradlew idea`, then opened the project, then i imported the unlinked gradle project. This was with IDEA 13. I tried again with 14 EAP, and now all the sources are attached. I was curious and tried it again with IDEA 13, and still no sources attached. Maybe this feature was introduced in 14?

Comment: I just tried the same with 14 EAP, and i now do not have the sources attached either. :(

Comment: After further investigation, it turned out it attaches automatically for some libraries, but for other ones it does not. `Guava` got attached but `commons-codec` not for example. :S

Comment: Ok, it seems `gradle idea` indeed correctly sets up all sources. The problem was when i linked into IntelliJ it incorrectly created the project structure, overwriting the one `gradle idea` created.

Answer (score 8):

If you do not want to run `gradle idea`, you can use a plugin to resolve sources automatically.

e.g. both IDEA and Eclipse compatible `build.gradle`:

```groovy
plugins {
  id "java"
  id "idea"
  id "eclipse"
}

idea {
  module {
    downloadSources = true
  }
}

eclipse {
  classpath {
    downloadSources = true
  }
}

dependencies {
  compile group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.6'
}
```

Comment: You can also download JavaDoc: ```idea {
  module {
    downloadJavadoc = true
    downloadSources = true
  }
}```

Answer (score 2):

This can be configured using the "Download sources" checkbox in the IDEA Settings under "Advanced Settings".

On macOS, this is found at:

- IntelliJ IDEA -> Settings… -> Advanced Settings -> Build Tools. Gradle -> Download sources

[image: IDEA on macOS with "Advanced Settings" showing the "Download sources" option]

Comment: This worked for me, and I really don't want to alter my Gradle build file to accomplish this, so I think this is an excellent solution.

Answer (score 0):

Creating the IDEA project using the `idea` Gradle task should automatically set up the project to download sources.

```
gradle idea
```

or

```
./gradlew idea
```